# How to remove elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to make logstash work with elasticsearch and Kibana. I had all the latest versions, but after I faced a few problems, I realized that I needed to install an older version, i.e., 0.20.6, of elasticsearch in order for it to work correctly with the latest version of logstash. So, I downloaded the older version, did an `rm -rf` of the older (v.0.90.x) one and installed the new (v.0.20.6) one. I tried to start it up. It starts, but then gives me repeating errors like:

```
[2013-07-29 14:24:04,718][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Dansen Macabre] [blog][2] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoveryFailedException: [blog][2]: Recovery failed from [Blob][UCFJzrBxQHOYOohF6scQMw][inet[/10.1.10.52:9300]] into [Dansen Macabre][-GzBNHLJSc2Do5DNTsn1jw][inet[/10.1.10.52:9301]]
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoveryTarget.doRecovery(RecoveryTarget.java:293)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoveryTarget.access$300(RecoveryTarget.java:62)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoveryTarget$2.run(RecoveryTarget.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [Blob][inet[/10.1.10.52:9300]][index/shard/recovery/startRecovery]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.engine.RecoveryEngineException: [blog][2] Phase[1] Execution failed
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.recover(RobinEngine.java:1123)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.recover(InternalIndexShard.java:526)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoverySource.recover(RecoverySource.java:116)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoverySource.access$1600(RecoverySource.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoverySource$StartRecoveryTransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(RecoverySource.java:328)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoverySource$StartRecoveryTransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(RecoverySource.java:314)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoverFilesRecoveryException: [blog][2] Failed to transfer [25] files with total size of [3.7kb]
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoverySource$1.phase1(RecoverySource.java:226)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.recover(RobinEngine.java:1116)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/CiC/BigData/elasticsearch-0.90.2/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/blog/2/index/_1_es090_0.doc (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexInput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:410)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory$NIOFSIndexInput.<init>(NIOFSDirectory.java:123)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory.openInput(NIOFSDirectory.java:80)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.RateLimitedFSDirectory.openInput(RateLimitedFSDirectory.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store.openInputRaw(Store.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.RecoverySource$1$1.run(RecoverySource.java:171)
    ... 3 more
```

As you can see, it is still trying to look for the v.0.90.x installation. My `localhost:9200` shows the following output:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Blob",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.2",
    "snapshot_build" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

How do I solve this to use v.0.20.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you still have 0.90 running. You need to shutdown it before you can switch to 0.20. The simplest way to do it is by running

```
curl -XPOST 10.1.10.52:9200/_shutdown
```

If this doesn't work, find the java process that elasticsearch is running in and kill it.

After 0.90 is down you might need to clean the directory again.

Comment: imotov, I re-did the whole thing, but when I try to log something into logstash to be stored in ES, I get a `ClusterBlockException - blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];:` error in logstash and a `Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x99214945, /127.0.0.1:56084 :> /127.0.0.1:9200]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text` error in ES. What is going on? I even tried `flush` and `delete`, but nothing seems to work on it. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue to me. This error means that Elasticsearch client inside logstash cannot join elasticsearch cluster. I would suggest asking a separate question that would include log files from both client and elasticsearch server as well as elasticsearch configuration.

Comment: I dunno how or why, but soon after the comment, it somehow worked. I deleted the old indices, and tried, it didn't work. I tried again, and it did. But now it's all fixed. I'll surely post a separate question from next time. Sorry! and Thank you!

Comment: This would never qualify for a SO question, and I guess you work for the ES team, and so I was curious. What are the names that pop up every time some task in ES is carried out? It changes all the time. One time I started ES and this came: `2013-07-30 12:31:51,213][INFO ][node                     ] [Union Jack]` and barely 5 minutes later, Union Jack was Dusk. What are those names? Why do they change and what do they signify? Thanks!

Comment: @CodingInCircles: Those are Marvel characters chosen at random by ES. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/configuration/ - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Jack_(comics)

Answer (score 0):

```
        In windows stop all the services. I mean Elastic search ,Kibana ,Logstash and beats if any.

        I installed them following http://robwillis.info/2016/05/installing-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-on-windows-server-2012-r2/ . Here  he has explained  the instaling steps very beautifully. Thanks A Lot.
I downloaded the zip and extracted them in a single folder as the below image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Installation steps are as below.

PS C:\windows\system32> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\ELKStack\elasticsearch-5.6.3\bin\elasticsearch-service install"
Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"
The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been installed.

PS C:\windows\system32> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\ELKStack\elasticsearch-5.6.3\bin\elasticsearch-service  manager"
Successfully started service manager for 'elasticsearch-service-x64'.

PS C:\windows\system32> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\ELKStack\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm install Logstash"
Service "Logstash" installed successfully!
PS C:\windows\system32> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\ELKStack\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm install kibana"
Service "kibana" installed successfully!
PS C:\windows\system32> PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File C:\ELKStack\filebeat-5.6.3-windows-x86_64\.\i
nstall-service-filebeat.ps1

Security Warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the Internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your
computer. Do you want to run C:\ELKStack\filebeat-5.6.3-windows-x86_64\install-service-filebeat.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): R

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  filebeat           filebeat


        Now to unistal I used the following method.

    Open windows powershell


        PS C:\windows\system32> PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File  C:\ELKStack\filebeat-5.6.3-windows-x86_64\un
        install-service-filebeat.ps1


        __GENUS          : 2
        __CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
        __SUPERCLASS     :
        __DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
        __RELPATH        :
        __PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
        __DERIVATION     : {}
        __SERVER         :
        __NAMESPACE      :
        __PATH           :
        ReturnValue      : 0


        PS C:\windows\system32> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\ELKStack\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm remove Kibana"
        Service "Kibana" removed successfully!

        PS C:\windows\system32> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\ELKStack\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm remove logstash"
        Service "Logstash" removed successfully!

        PS C:\windows\system32> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\ELKStack\elasticsearch-5.6.3\bin\elasticsearch-service.bat remove"
        The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been removed`enter code here`


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooHa8.png
```